# MySql SUM subset

Tags: mysql

I have this result from my query

```
SELECT CT.*, CW.id_cw, CW.suivie_cw FROM ct AS CT 
JOIN sw AS SW ON CT.id_sw = SW.id_sw 
JOIN cw AS CW ON CT.id_sw = CW.id_cw
WHERE SW.`dateCrea_sw` 
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2022-12-31 23:59:59') 
AND CT.id_format IN (10, 11, 12) 
AND CT.quantite > 0
AND CW.suivie_cw = 1 GROUP BY CT.id_produit;
```

[image]

What I want is to get the SUM of the third column `quantite`.

I tried something like

```
SELECT SUM((SELECT CT.quantite FROM ct AS CT 
JOIN sw AS SW ON CT.id_sw = SW.id_sw 
JOIN cw AS CW ON CT.id_sw = CW.id_cw
WHERE SW.`dateCrea_sw` 
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2022-12-31 23:59:59') 
AND CT.id_format IN (10, 11, 12) 
AND CT.quantite > 0
AND CW.suivie_cw = 1 GROUP BY CT.id_produit)) FROM ct
```

But I got the following error

`#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`

That's seems logical to me since I would get the sum of these rows.
As work around I use a temporary table to insert the result of the first query, then perform the sum on that table.

There is a way to perform that in one query ?

Comment: Attempt to solve problem added

Comment: Depending on your MySQL version, you could use `SUM() OVER ()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap your original query in one that only exposes the desired column
2. Wrap *that* query in one that sums that column